# Unlock windows session remotely

Tags: windows-7, authentication, windows-authentication

Use case : my mother wants to be able to allow the opening of a windows (7) session on my little brother's computer on a "on-demand" basis, without being on premises.

Basically, unlocking the session via her smartphone of by giving him a one-time code generated by a device would do.

I have seen many articles suggesting Rohos key Generator, but that requires the smartphone/USB key to be physically present and does not require her remote approval.
I have also seen many Token products (like RSA SecurID) but most of them rely on a corporate-grade AD architecture and seems way overkill (and overpriced) for such a simple need.

Any inputs ?

Comment: @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "$sessionid=((quser $env:USERNAME | select -Skip 1) -split '\s+')[2]; tscon $sessionid /dest:console" 2> UnlockErrors.log ...Run this script as administrator [More Help](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream/discussions/0/617335934139051123/)

Comment: This command seems to unlock a console session, potentially from an RDP Admin session ? that doesn't seem user-friendly enough AT ALL for my need, although it means what I ask is doable